Is 3000 ballistic missiles a credible deterrent?

https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/89433/32479

The above link says that there is credible information that Iran possesses 3000 ballistic missiles stored in its fortified underground bunkers.
Is 3000 ballistic missiles a credible deterrent against a possible US invasion or an all-out war between US-assisted Israel and Iran?

Hezbollah reportedly had 150,000 rockets and missiles that could reach some part of Israel. True though, the warheads on many of these are smaller. But clearly that hasn't stopped Israel from killing Hezbollah's leadership 2-3 times over etc.
Wikipedia also tells us that "1,115 V-2s were fired at the United Kingdom". Those were 1st gen ballistic missiles (unlike V-1s). Other sites give higher numbers, e.g. 3,000 even 9,000 the BBC claims (counting those that didn't even reach the shores).
Missile forces are not a very cost effective way to project power, short of them being nuclear tipped. There's an interesting comparison with older generations of jets I read somewhere, alas I don't have the link handy. Essentially the latter pay for themselves in a few bombing runs relative to [long-range] missiles. True, latest generation jets are more expensive, and they'd perhaps need around 100 runs to break even, but it also depends how much the missiles cost. (Comparing e.g. the cost of B-2 bombers with (cruise) missiles was a sport in some corners. OTOH the numbers given there underestimated the final B-2 cost by an order of magnitude.)
Consider also that Russia was not making much headway in Ukraine (after the initial semi-surprise attack) until it started using its air force properly. The tonnage of glide bombs their fixed wing aircraft deliver vastly exceeds what their [conventional] missiles can do, and they surely have more than Iran. Ukraine is getting hit by ~100 glide bombs per day. That's like a repeat of Iran's strike every other day. Meanwhile Russia fires about 150-200 ballistic missiles per month. (This includes conversions from SAMs.) There is of course a difference where the latter can hit, absent air supremacy.
Missiles are not useless however, as (esp. the ballistic ones) they can be harder to hit than jets, and don't incur a loss of attackers' life when intercepted, so may be politically more acceptable to a [human life] loss-averse country. And so can strike deeper in contested air spaces. But they are not some superweapon.


Is 3000 ballistic missiles a credible deterrent against a possible US
invasion or an all-out war between US-assisted Israel and Iran?

Standing alone, no.
Israel's Iron Dome missile defenses are highly capable, so only a few would get through and if Israel were determined enough, it would strike Iran anyway. And, Iran has no viable way to attack U.S. territory. U.S. military forces also have air defenses that would make it hard to Iran to even do serious damage to U.S. military forces at foreign bases in the region.
This said, overall, Iran's has one of the more potent military forces in the world. Among the countries that are a threat to U.S. Navy forces, only China, North Korea, and Russia rival it.
Iran has a significant Air Force and a fairly large and competent Army.
Iran's military, collectively, is more than sufficient to deter a U.S. or Israel ground force invasion of Iran, even if it is probably not sufficient to deter air or missile strikes on Iran from the U.S. or Israel on it, or a highly specific, short, special forces raid on a particular target. Israel doesn't have the resources to launch a ground war invasion of Iran and the U.S. doesn't have the stomach to fight another massive ground war in Asia unless failing to do so posed an existential threat to the U.S., which it does not.
Of course, this would change dramatically, if Iran secured nuclear warheads for its missiles. It has a nuclear program that has been working towards that end for decades, and has some military ties to both Russia and North Korea, which might be willing to provide it with a few nuclear warheads for the right price.

The last paragraph is quite or will become quite important in the near future I guess.

I doubt anyone would sell Iran assembled nuclear weapons, and I also doubt that they would buy them. Iran needs confidence that they will go boom when somebody pushes the trigger, and short of a test the only way is to have their own people build them. That being said, Iran is very close to building their own weapons and a few dozen kg of weapons-grade material would make a difference.

@o.m. I could easily see Russia, which is dependent on Iran for drones it vitally needs for its war in Ukraine provide Iran with some tactical nuclear warheads in order to keep that supply of drones flowing.

@ohwilleke, wouldn't Iran be almost as happy about HEU, and Russia given much more plausible deniability?

Deterrence depends on two mirrored factors:

The ability and will to inflict unacceptable damage on an attacker if the attacker violates the interests of the defender.
The credible restraint not to inflict unacceptable damage on an attacker if the attacker does not violate the interests of the defender.

A couple of terms are highlighted here.
What constitutes unacceptable damage is a subjective assessment of the mindset of the opposing leaders. For instance, there was the (quite possibly racist) belief in the West that the Chinese Communists under Mao would gamble with tens or hundreds of millions of their own citizens if the end result left them poised to lead a world revolution. The Soviets were seen as less likely to gamble -- the UK and France built the capacity to take out a few major cities of the Soviet Union with their secure second strike capability and considered that sufficient in view of the US-USSR balance.
3,000 conventional ballistic missile warheads is similar to what Germany or Japan received in the largest single air raids of WWII. They did not fold after one such raid. But then the war was already ongoing, which gives a different dynamic.
The ability to inflict this damage may be easier to estimate than the will to inflict it if the use of the deterrence potential against the attacker would lead to similar strikes against the defender. The Cold War reached the level of mutually assured destruction. Israel and Iran probably do not have mutually assured destruction yet unless the Iranian nuclear program is further ahead than generally believed.
Iran might or might not have the fissile material for half a dozen nukes or so, and a simple-but-untested design. (Probably only Iran knows for sure. Israel and the US will have better estimates than I do in my armchair, but those will be estimates only.) Israel almost certainly has more fissile material and better designs. Assuming Iran has no nukes, or no viable delivery systems, the question would be if Iran is willing to accept an asymmetrical outcome (Israel damaged, Iran destroyed) and if Israel believes that.
Think back to the outcome of the Vietnam war. In the end North Vietnam won, because North Vietnam was willing to pay a much higher price than the US and the US was unwilling to increase their price.
Deterrence also depends on the interests at stake for both sides. This plays into what damage is not unacceptable as a price for hurting the other side. Every day there are countless examples of successful and unsuccessful deterrence worldwide, often for very minor stakes. "Do not raise the tariffs on my exports, or I will raise the tariffs on your exports, and consumers in both countries suffer."
Both Israel and Iran have religious convictions at stake in this conflict, as well as realpolitik, which makes this a bit unpredictable.
And this ties into the last point. Deterrence only works if the attacker believes that restraint by the attacker will lead to restraint by the defender. Otherwise, the so-called "deterrence potential" becomes cause for a preemptive war.
Guessing what the Israeli leadership really thinks is out of scope for this board. But from their public statements, the Israeli government seems to believe that the Iranian government is implacably hostile to Israel, and unwilling to come to a detente. This might prompt Israel to set the objective deterrence potential of 3,000 missiles aside and to strike at a moment of their choice, rather than handing the initiative to Iran to launch those missiles at another moment.

This might prompt Israel to set the objective deterrence potential of 3,000 missiles aside and to strike at a moment of their choice, rather than handing the initiative to Iran to launch those missiles at another moment. --- This statement assumes that Israel is in control of the situation. I would heavily doubt that and hence I am not accepting this answer.

@user366312, deterrence always aims at the decisionmakers on the other side. So the only one to decide if Iran is deterring Israel is Israel, and the only one to decide if Israel is deterring Iran is Iran.
